# How do I install boto3 without pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, package, boto3, apt-get

My pip package is corrupted. I need to install boto3 using apt-get but I get the following error when I do apt-get install python-boto3:

E: Package 'python-boto3' has no installation candidate

Can someone please help me find a alternate way or some way to make apt-get work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use apt-get to install python packages. In order to install a python package, **pip** resolves dependencies and build wheels. **apt-get** doesn't have the functionality to do the same.

You can purge the previous installation of pip:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
```

then install a new one:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

finally, try installing boto3:

```
sudo pip install boto3
```

Comment: can you attach the output here ( https://www.protectedtext.com/pip_output    password: 1234 )?